# remove shared library from sshd

Tags: linux, ssh, hacking, libraries, rootkit

```
mv /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.9 /root
service sshd restart
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd: error while loading shared libraries: libkeyutils.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
                                                           [FAILED]
```

How do I remove it from SSHD?

Need to fix this:
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?p=8548338&postcount=4

REF about this exploit now that I've heard about it:
http://blog.solidshellsecurity.com/2013/02/18/0day-linuxcentos-sshd-spam-exploit-libkeyutils-so-1-9/

> They are not logging in with root, nor are they even spawning a bash
>   process. If the lib is moved out, and sshd is restarted they cannot
>   login anymore fwiw.
>
> The key is finding out how they are getting in. Fully upgraded, ssh
>   key restricted sshd, on non-standard ports are being compromised. None
>   of my customers are, but I have been getting alot of sales inquiries
>   with this issue so I don't know the full history of the machines.

```
[/lib64]# rpm -vV openssh
.........    /etc/ssh
.........  c /etc/ssh/moduli
.........    /usr/bin/ssh-keygen
.........    /usr/libexec/openssh
.........    /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-keysign
.........    /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/CREDITS
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/ChangeLog
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/INSTALL
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/LICENCE
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/OVERVIEW
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/PROTOCOL
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/PROTOCOL.agent
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/README
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/README.dns
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/README.nss
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/README.platform
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/README.privsep
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/README.smartcard
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/README.tun
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/TODO
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-5.3p1/WARNING.RNG
.........  d /usr/share/man/man1/ssh-keygen.1.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man8/ssh-keysign.8.gz
[/lib64]# rpm -vV openssh-clients
S.5....T.  c /etc/ssh/ssh_config
.........    /usr/bin/.ssh.hmac
.........    /usr/bin/scp
.........    /usr/bin/sftp
.........    /usr/bin/slogin
.........    /usr/bin/ssh
.........    /usr/bin/ssh-add
.........    /usr/bin/ssh-agent
.........    /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id
.........    /usr/bin/ssh-keyscan
.........  d /usr/share/man/man1/scp.1.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man1/sftp.1.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man1/slogin.1.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man1/ssh-add.1.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man1/ssh-agent.1.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man1/ssh-copy-id.1.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man1/ssh-keyscan.1.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man1/ssh.1.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man5/ssh_config.5.gz
[/lib64]# rpm -vV openssh-server
.......T.  c /etc/pam.d/ssh-keycat
S.5....T.  c /etc/pam.d/sshd
.........    /etc/rc.d/init.d/sshd
S.5....T.  c /etc/ssh/sshd_config
.........  c /etc/sysconfig/sshd
.........    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
.........    /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-keycat
.........    /usr/sbin/.sshd.hmac
.........    /usr/sbin/sshd
.........    /usr/share/doc/openssh-server-5.3p1
.........  d /usr/share/doc/openssh-server-5.3p1/HOWTO.ssh-keycat
.........  d /usr/share/man/man5/moduli.5.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man5/sshd_config.5.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man8/sshd.8.gz
.........    /var/empty/sshd
```

and

```
[/lib64]# rpm -qf /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.9
file /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.9 is not owned by any package
[/lib64]# rpm -vV keyutils-libs
....L....    /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1
.........    /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
.........    /usr/share/doc/keyutils-libs-1.4
.........  d /usr/share/doc/keyutils-libs-1.4/LICENCE.LGPL
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?p=8548338&postcount=4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SSH daemon and system ***may be compromised***!!

You can't trust the existing SSH daemon installed on the server.

For a quick check, run an RPM verification of the existing package. You can do this with:

```
rpm -vV openssh-server
rpm -vV openssh-clients
rpm -vV openssh
```

Grep the output of each of those commands for `S\.5`. This will tell you if the binaries have changed.

A temp fix is to reinstall your openssh setup, but that's beyond the scope of this question. See the following...

[How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

[sshd immediately core dumps after fsck repair](https://serverfault.com/questions/382093/sshd-immediately-core-dumps-after-fsck-repair/382095#382095)

[Entries in `/etc/inittab` below last line - possible hack?](https://serverfault.com/questions/435181/entries-in-etc-inittab-below-last-line-possible-hack/435191#435191)

Comment: I ran a MD5 on the sshd binary and it matches a clean server. posted output above all looks find

Comment: `rpm -qf /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.9` and `rpm -vV keyutils-libs`

Comment: posted above...

Comment: After looking at the output, it looks like 1.3 is the real version and 1.9 is not really suppose to be there? Do I RPM remove it?

Comment: `rm` the file and reinstall openssh.

Comment: How do I uninstall openssh and reinstall? Via YUM?

Comment: @TiffanyWalker [See this link.](http://serverfault.com/questions/382093/sshd-immediately-core-dumps-after-fsck-repair/382095#382095)

Comment: All I got was "Installed package openssh-5.3p1-81.el6_3.x86_64 (from updates) not available." so guess this means need to manually do it in some way?

Comment: @TiffanyWalker, that could mean simply that that version has been replaced by a newer one. Try just updating.

Comment: In any case, whatever forensic analysis is to be done should be made from a clean start, e.g. use installation media for rescue and be careful not to run anything on the suspect disk. In any case, the only course of action that would let me sleep at night would be a full reinstall. My condolences.

Comment: @ewwhite: bad advice to rm the file, as there's typically a symlink pointing to it hence applications will fail (ssh, sshd, nslookup, slogin, svn, etc) - see the WebHostingTalk thread for correct way to do this, which requires re-installing the relevant SSH packages, ensuring libkeyutils 1.3 is correct and has symlink, then renaming the file, then ensuring ssh can be run correctly, and then doing a reboot.  There are some people who just rm'ed the file and now can't get in via SSH on reboot, so be sure there's another way in (hosting control panel, webmin, etc).

Comment: I don't agree this is an exact duplicate of the compromised server canonical question - it's an ongoing issue with many people trying to find out exactly how the attackers are getting in.  Specific remediation steps, and analysis of how the attack is accomplished, are much more useful than generic compromised server advice.